# Using scanf function

Tags: c, scanf

I am try the code below.But when I input the integer,then program does not ask for character.Program execute the printf line.How should i avoid above problem?.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
    char a[5];
    int p;
    printf("data\n");
    scanf("%d",&p);
    scanf ("%c",&a);
    printf("--> %c %d\n",a,p);
}
```

Comment: Honestly, the best way to avoid the problem is to use `fgets` and `strtol`.  `scanf` is too fragile to be used reliably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a space in `scanf` like this:

```
scanf (" %c",&a);
        ^-------note
```

So that the trailing newline is eaten up. Once you hit enter after giving the integer input - there is a trailing newline character in the buffer which the second call to `scanf` reads. Also `main` as per ISO should return `int`

Also this statement is incorrect:

```
char a[5];
printf("--> %c %d\n",a,p);
```

You are reading a char and printing an array. You simply need:

```
char a;
printf("--> %c %d\n",a,p);
```

If you want to read (or take input) array of chars then use [`fgets`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/). For `char a[5]` do something like:

```
fgets (a, 5 , stdin)
```

Since fgets is buffer safe.

Comment: Its type is different but it will return the same value.